# rails running methods after view is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to show a spinning 'loading' image while my method computes some things and returns the results to the view.

Currently, it just looks as though the page isn't loading at all and then does (it's performing the method).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be for the page you're loading to simply be the loading indicator, and have it do an AJAX request to retrieve the rest of the results (you can use jQuery or something similar to issue the request and then insert the results into the document).

If you're feeling up to it, you could instead use the HTTP streaming support that's new in Rails 3.1.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming

Comment: Bear in mind ajax won't support javascript disabled and potentially search engines. I'd have a good look at http streaming as linked.

Comment: thanks all -- unfortunately some of the gems I need don't support 3.1, so I'll have to find another way to speed things up...